# How to use MathJax on my site without cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, mathjax

I noticed that when [including MathJax in the recommended way](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html) my webpage is apparently placing and/or reading cookies on the user's machine. The cookies are from cloudflare.com.

(1) Am I correct that MathJax uses cookies? (Why?)

(2) Can I configure the settings so as not to place or read cookies from the visitor's computer? If necessary to do this, I can host MathJax myself although they generally do not recommend it.

(3) (Bonus) What information does Cloudflare and/or MathJax collect and store about visitors to my page?

Searching the linked documentation didn't give me any results. (If you are curious, my reasons for asking are mainly privacy related. I guess in light of GDPR there could even be legal implications...)

Answer (score 1):

Reading from [the source code](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/master/unpacked/MathJax.js):

> Read cookie and set up menu defaults
>
> (set the locale according to the cookie)
>
> (adjust the jax to accommodate renderer preferences)

Hence, no information colletion, no you cannot avoid cookie....

Comment: Thanks for this info so far. I don't have JS experience, but maybe I could serve it myself and delete this part of the code (e.g. default locale)? I wonder what the benefit of the locale is here.